# jquery not picking up html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, tags

So I have the following HTML

```
<div class="tmpl" id="query_tmpl">
<tr>
    <td><a href="#" class="group"></a></td>
    <td class="primary_email"></td>
</tr>
</div>
```

and the following JS:

```
 console.log($('#query_tmpl').html());
```

For some reason this only logs the 'a' tag.  (Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/L8RQq/ )

Why does this happen and how do I get around it so that I can properly pick up the tr/td? I'm using jQuery 1.9.2 if that makes any difference.

Update:
Yes, the markup is 'bad html', but the whole point of this question is how to get around that. Using the HTML present and without altering it, how can I grab the contents even though it's 'bad'?

Comment: Because your HTML is invalid. You can't have tr and td tags outside a table.

Comment: Wrong Html Markup
TR tag cannot be wrapped under DIV

Comment: you need `<table>` tags wrapping the `<tr>`: http://jsfiddle.net/L8RQq/3/

Comment: I know it's 'bad markup', but my question is how do I get around it... I need someway to create templates and in this instance our template inputs trs within a table instead of other content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it like this

```
    <table class="tmpl" id="query_tmpl">
         <tr>
            <td><a href="#" class="group"></a></td>
            <td class="primary_email"></td>
         </tr>
    </table>
```

Then it will surely work correctly

Comment: This won't work because inserting a table within a table won't work. This is aimed to be a template.

Comment: I guess that would technically work since it keeps the proper html structure and the class/id structure... Let me see if that will work with the system since this is used in multiple places. Good idea.

Comment: I had to change it slightly, but it worked. Thanks! :
    <table class="tmpl">
    <tbody id="query_tmpl">
         <tr>
            <td><a href="#" class="group"></a></td>
            <td class="primary_email"></td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `table` tags around your `tr`. Try this:

```
<div class="tmpl" id="query_tmpl">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#" class="group"></a></td>
            <td class="primary_email"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**[This will log the div's contents properly](http://jsfiddle.net/L8RQq/4/)**.

the reason it wasn't logging, is because the browser sees some invalid `tr` and `td` tags, and removes those, because they can only be in a `table`, leaving you with only the `a`.

If you can't change the markup, tell the person / company that wrote that markup to fix it. It's invalid HTML.

Comment: The point is to be able to grab the HTML within the div tag without adding a table tag. I'm trying to create a template and I want to be able to create multiple rows within an already present table using a template

Comment: @AramPapazian: not even `innerHTML` is grabbing the content. I'd suggest trying to add it to a variable in a script block, or something like that. I'm not sure a template like that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pick up tr's or td's you can use css manipulation functions such as `children([selector])` where `selector` is eventually a `class`